# How do I convert an object to array to push an item into it - Javscript

Tags: javascript

I have a data object, so I want to push an item into it, I understand that we can't push into an object so I want to convert the object into an array, push my item into it and then convert back to an object

```
{
  Activity: 'digitalLoan',
  digitalLoan_type: 'first_advance',
  firstdvance_acc_number: '321e132e1'
}
```

How do I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you came to a conclusion without even trying it. Check code below:

```js
var records = {
  Activity: 'digitalLoan',
  digitalLoan_type: 'first_advance',
  firstdvance_acc_number: '321e132e1'
}

records.user_email = "adesanya"

console.log(records)
```

Comment: Wow! my bad, I made a mistake this is way better then.

Answer (score 0):

So here is something simple I did to achieve that.

1. Collect the data object

   `const records = context._activity.value;
   console.log(records);`
2. Convert the  object to an array 
   `var result = Object.keys(records).map(function (key) {
   return { [key]: records[key] };
   });
   console.log(result);`
3. Push some data

   `result.push({"user_email":"adesanya"})`
4. Convert the result array back to object

   `var newRecs = Object.assign({}, ...result);
   console.log(newRecs);`

Comment: You couldn't do `records.user_email = "adesanya"`?

Comment: records is an object 

`{
  Activity: 'digitalLoan',
  digitalLoan_type: 'first_advance',
  firstdvance_acc_number: '321e132e1'
}`

Comment: This `records.user_email = "adesanya"` is not going to push adesanya into records object